# Stopping Jenkins from Incrementing Job Numbers When Restarting from a Stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, rpm

I'm new to Jenkins, and here's my issue: every time I rerun a stage, Jenkins increments the job number. Here's the catch: my pipeline involves creating and deploying RPM packages, with the job number embedded in their names. So, when I retry at a stage after the package creation and reach the deployment stage, it fails to locate the RPM package because the job number and the RPM package number don't match up.

Is there a way to stop Jenkins from changing the job number?